# mat-nav-list: routerLinkActive class applied after click

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-routing

I have a `mat-nav-list` in my application that displays the menu on the left. I have added `routerLinkActive="selected-item"` to it to highlight the currently selected menu item.

Whenever a menu item is clicked, the class is not applied. It gets applied only after I click somewhere else in the page.

Below is the snippet of my code:

```html
<mat-nav-list (click)="menuItemClicked()" class="menu-list">
    <a  *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" mat-list-item
        [routerLink]="menuItem.routerLink" routerLinkActive="selected-item">

        <mat-icon [svgIcon]="menuItem.icon" matListIcon></mat-icon>
        <span>{{ menuItem.label }}</span>
    </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

```css
.selected-item {
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #f47431;
}
```

Here's a Stackblitz which reproduces the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wuabhz?file=src/app/list-single-selection-example.html

Select one of the boot items and click somewhere else and you'll see the class `selected-item` gets applied.

Is there a way to overcome this issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

@prerak-sola

I noticed the same.
The reason for this is that the item still have ':focus' until you click somewhere else.

**You could**

### 1. use the same color on the 'item-active' as mat-list-item:focus

*(if you don't have a need for a darker shade or different color)*

```css
.active-link {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.mat-nav-list .mat-list-item:focus{
  /* default bg color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
  /* ovrride bg color to match your item-active*/
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

}
```

```html
<!-- list item is '<a mat-list-item>' -->
'a mat-list-item'

    <mat-nav-list>
         <a mat-list-item  *ngFor="let link of links" [routerLink]="link.path" routerLinkActive="active-link">{{ link.name }}</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
```

### 2. Or probably better wrap your list-item in a `<mat-list-item>`

- *note that the 'routerLinkActive' is placed in the `<mat-list-item>`*
- this will override the 'background-color' from .mat-list-item:focus

```html
<!-- list item is '<mat-list-item>' -->
      'a mat-list-item'
      <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item  *ngFor="let link of links" routerLinkActive="active-link">
         <a matLine [routerLink]="link.path" style="width: 100%;">{{ link.name }}</a>
         <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
         </button>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
```

```css
.active-link {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

// .mat-nav-list .mat-list-item:focus{
//    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
// }
```